# Ajax Not Working If The Handler is Located Outside Plugin Submenu Page Function

Tags: plugins, ajax, sub-menu

I am using wordpress ajax to trigger a submission. I located the submission code in the submenu page, because of it is have conflict with the function in plugin main page. The problem here is, I should placed the ajax handler in the submenu page function while it will not triggered if it is placed there.

It always returning `0` if the handler is located in the submenu page function. I had added `nopriv` in the handler hook and also localize the javascript.

The **[Ajax example from Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)** is also not working if I put it inside the submenu page function of my plugin.

My question:

- How to make wordpress ajax working while its handler is placed inside submenu page function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please paste your code here ? It is easy to understand the code than the prose here.

Comment: The ajax code is very simple and just a test, not far different with the code from this link http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. My function is too large to be posted here.

Comment: Have you tried placing the code in your plugin file outside of the submenu page function?

Comment: I have. That's why I am asking this question `How to make wordpress ajax working while its handler is placed inside submenu page function?`